# Does $\int_0^2\frac{1}{\ln(x)}dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

Given the following integral:

$$ \int_0^2 \frac{1}{\ln(x)} dx $$

Does it converge?

Iv'e gone this far:
$$ \int_0^2 \frac{1}{\ln(x)} dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln(x)} dx + \int_1^2 \frac{1}{\ln(x)} dx $$

Now I'm having trouble calculating each. I can only tell that: $ \int \frac{1}{\ln(x)} dx \gt \int\frac1x dx $

Comment: $\frac{1}{\log(x)}$ is not greater than $1/x$ for $x<1$ since $\log(x)<0$ for $x<1$.

Comment: Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

> **PRIMER:**

> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function along with Bernoulli's Inequality that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities

> $$\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1 \tag 1$$

> for $x>0$.

---

Note from $(1)$, that we have for $x>0$, $x\ne1$

$$\frac{x}{x-1} \ge \frac{1}{\log(x)}\ge \frac{1}{x-1}$$

Therefore, the singularity at $x=1$ renders the integral divergent.

However, the Cauchy Principal Value

$$\text{PV}\int_0^2 \frac{1}{\log(x)}\,dx=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\left(\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\frac{1}{\log(x)}\,dx+\int_{1+\epsilon}^2 \frac{1}{\log(x)}\,dx\right)$$

does converge.

Comment: @Squirrel Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Just continuing from Mark's answer, in terms of [Gregory coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients):
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\text{PV}\int_{0}^{2}\frac{dx}{\log(x)} &=& \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\varepsilon}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{\log(1+x)}+\frac{1}{\log(1-x)}\right)\,dx\\&=& 2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{G_{2n+1}}{2n+1} \\&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(x+2)-\log(x)}{\pi^2+\log^2(x)}\,dx\end{eqnarray*}$$
but both the series representation and the integral one are quite slow-converging to 
$$\text{LogIntegral}(2)=1.04516378\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

If $1\ne x$ then $\log x < x-1$.  You can tell that's true just because the tangent line to $y=\ln x$ at $x=1$ is $y=x-1$ and the graph is concave downward at that point.  Therefore
$$
\int_1^2 \frac {dx} {\log x} > \int_1^2 \frac {dx} {x-1} = +\infty.
$$
In a similar way, one can deduce that
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\log x} = -\infty.
$$

In this sort of situation you can find things like
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\,\downarrow\,0} \left( \int_0^{1-\varepsilon} \frac{dx}{\log x} + \int_{1+\varepsilon}^2 \frac{dx}{\log x} \right) \ne \lim_{\varepsilon\,\downarrow\,0} \left( \int_0^{1-\varepsilon} \frac{dx}{\log x} + \int_{1+2\varepsilon}^2 \frac{dx}{\log x} \right).
$$
The limit on the left above is the Cauchy principal value.  I think that exists.  Maybe I'll be $\text{back }\ldots$

Comment: This looks familiar.  ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV : But I used $\varepsilon$ where you used $\epsilon$, so mine is better.  Right? $\qquad$

Comment: Yes, absolutely.